# Replace same character in multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to run this basic replace on columns field01 through field39 without requiring 39 queries:

```
UPDATE leads
    SET field01 = REPLACE(field01, ' ', '+')
     WHERE field40 = 'in_process';
```

If it is easier to run with PHP, that would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple columns within a single query:

```
UPDATE leads
    SET field01 = REPLACE(field01, ' ', '+'),
        field02 = REPLACE(field02, ' ', '+'),
        . . .
        field39 = REPLACE(field39, ' ', '+')
    WHERE field40 = 'in_process';
```

Typing out the code is cumbersome,  You can generate the code using a spreadsheet.

I should not that having dozens of columns that contain similar information is often a sign of bad database design.  There is a good chance that you need a junction table, with one row per lead and field value.

Comment: Thanks for what is an obvious time-saving solution. (Bonking myself that I hadn't thought to do that.) However, I actually was hoping for some sort of LOOP or PHP code that could go through the whole process at once. NOTE: These are not similar columns. However, they have "spaces" input by user that needed to become a plus (+) before posting to another server.